# PHP upscale an image?

Tags: php, image, scale

I am new to php and trying to learn about image upscaling. can you please show me how can I upscale an image to a certain size? For example, I would like to re-size the following image while keeping the aspect ratio. If this can be done, can you please show me with an example
[image]

Comment: Why would you use PHP instead of changing the size with jQuery/Javascript? I fail to see the need for doing that server-side?

Comment: Check out [`PHP GD`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). It has all functions you need. In this case you would need: 1. Any of the `imagecreate*` functions to load the original. 2. Create a blank destination image using `imagecreatetruecolor` 3. Use `imagecopyresized` to copy the original to the destination. 4. Save image to file using `imagepng`, `imagegif` or `imagejpeg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("osaka.jpg");
$source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
$source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
$dest_imagex = 300;
$dest_imagey = 200;
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
```

Poor quality, but fast:

```
imagecopyresized($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
```

Best quality, but slow:

```
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete. To save the image we need to call `imagejpeg($dest_image, $destination)`

Answer (score 1):

You can upscale an image in html/CSS, by setting one side to a custom length, and setting the other side to 'auto'. There is no need to upscale it in php, as the upscaled image doesn't contain any more information than then the 'normal' version. It only consumes more bandwidth.

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" style="width: 50px; height: auto;" />

<img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" style="width: 200px; height: auto;" />
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Rd9z/).

Comment: This is the best solution unless users need to download the image in the upscale version

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use PHP to do that, you can look at "imagecopyresampled" function:

[imagecopyresampled on php.net with examples](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

But if you want to keep ratio, you have to calculate it and apply manually to width and height.

Answer (score 0):

**Image up-scaling**

```
// creating image resource from image path (also supports url)
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($destinationReal); // 1150x235 px

// getting source image dimension
$source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
$source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);

// set new image dimension
$dest_imagex = 1150;
$dest_imagey = 348; // in my case I only upscale the height

// create image (in memory)
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

// save new image
imagejpeg($dest_image, $destination);
```